# action_link (stream.publish) containing app domain doesn't resolve properly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publish, facebook-wall

i actually dont know if this a bug or if it's simply prohibited to use the app domain in an action link. Simple example:

**THE LINK PARAM WORKS WITH ANY GIVEN URL.. ONLY MY APP DOMAIN WONT WORK PROPERLY...** Its a valid url, absolutely standard... i tried if with several ones and all work. It seems tha action link just refuses to contain my app domain.

[...]

```
'actions' => array( array   ('name' => 'Testing action links'
                            , 'link' => 'http://www.google.de') //I JUST CHANGE THIS
                            )
```

[...]

One interesting thing is how these links are outputted on the users wall:

**If all is fine (all domains except app domain):**

```
<a onmousedown="UntrustedLink.bootstrap($(this), &quot;0AQCqzYSt&quot;, event, bagof(null));" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.teacho.net/?ref=nf">Testing action links</a>
```

**If i use my app domain:**

```
<a rel="async" href="http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=155994747814732&amp;method=permissions.request&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myappdomain.de&amp;response_type=token&amp;display=page&amp;ref=nf" class="">Testing action links</a>
```

Does anyone konw why this happens???

Thank you in advance!